# Eclipse plug-in not working in deployed feature

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I am developing several eclipse plug-ins which I bundle as a single eclipse feature.  In the development environment I can run "as eclipse application" and see all the functionality of all plug-ins working great.  When I package this as a feature, and install the feature to a clean eclipse installation, some of the plug-ins work but others do not.  Specifically, I do not see any error message during installation or runtime, but for example, an editor and a wizard that one of the plug-ins provides are just not there.

Any advice on what could be different and go wrong between running "as eclipse application" and running the installed set of plug-ins?  Also, if error messages are generated from the new eclipse installation, where could I see them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your feature may depend on some plugins that are available in your development environment but not in the *clean install*.

It may help to start eclipse with the `-console` option and study the statuses of the plugins. Try to start you plugins manually (from the console), it will report unresolved dependencies.